# Dependencies in paths - requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I'm using requireJS and ilighbox script. 
There are 4 required files for lightbox to work.
Now I have code like this:

```
require.config({
            baseUrl: "/js/",
            paths: {
                jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min",
                jqueryAnimationFrame: "libs/ilightbox/js/jquery.requestAnimationFrame",
                jqueryMouseWheel: "libs/ilightbox/js/jquery.mousewheel",
                ilightbox:"libs/ilightbox/js/ilightbox.packed"
            }
        });
```

Can I use depencies like in shim?
ex:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/js/",
  paths: {
    jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min",
    ilightbox:{
      "libs/ilightbox/js/ilightbox.packed":
      deps: [
        'jquery',
        "libs/ilightbox/js/jquery.requestAnimationFrame",
        "libs/ilightbox/js/jquery.mousewheel"
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shims - but they are based on packages, not on paths :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.7.2',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'console': 'lib/console'
    }, 
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        console: {
            exports: "console"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use shim. I want to use depencies in paths